# custom object not queryable

Tags: visualforce, soql, query, workbench

[image]I have a custom object, say CS in my org. User U1 has profile P1 and P1 has all the crud permission on that object. Still while logging as U1, and try to query that particular object it errors out : sObject type  is not supported. Can anyone help what other permission needs to set in order to make that particular custom object queryable for that profile ? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to query from developer console ? or via VF page code?

Comment: i've tried in VF page code, then also tried from workbench, and the object is not availabe in the queryable object list

Comment: Check if the profile of the User is 'API Enabled'?

Comment: its working fine for other custom objects, but not for this object

Comment: Please provide the query you were using.

Comment: SELECT count() FROM Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c that errors out: ERROR at Row:1:Column:21
sObject type 'Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: the object is not at all available in the list of objects in SOQL option

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the Object detail page in this question ?

Comment: edited the post @Amit Bangad

Comment: 'In Development' is the issue, I updated the answer!

Comment: If you are getting this error and you don't know why, check for namespaces.  If you don't namespace your object while querying, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if one of below things resolve your issue.

- Make sure there exists a object with API name that you are using.
  Most likely you are mistaking the object API name. Go to setup >
  create> Object and check the API name.
- Go to profile level and check if 'API Enabled' permission is checked.

In your screenshot
 - The status of the object shows that its in development. This is the issue.

Comment: both the conditions are right in place, profile is api enabled and the object api name is correct, still its failing

Answer (score 1):

The Deployment Status for the object is set to **In Development**

Comment: that is correct !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any namespace and also Check your profile and user license - 
sounds like you might have a chatter only license

Comment: it is a Salesforce Platform user and also there is no namespace defined here